# Win32 API - AppendMenuA throwing conversion error

Tags: c++, winapi

I have the following code to create a simple menu in C++ with the Win32 API:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HMENU hSubMenu=CreatePopupMenu();
        AppendMenuA(hSubMenu,MF_STRING,9002,("Do This"));

        HMENU hMenu = CreateMenu();
        AppendMenuA(hMenu, MF_STRING|MF_POPUP, hSubMenu,"Tool");
        SetMenu(hwnd, hMenu);

    }
```

`"Tool"` is the Main menu, under which `"Do This"` should be displayed. I am trying to follow Microsoft's docs, but I keep getting the below error:

[image]

As per the doc: [AppendMenuA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-appendmenua)

> if the uFlags parameter is set to MF_POPUP, 3rd parameter will be a handle to the drop-down menu or submenu.

Why is it not working?

Comment: Please don't (only) show the result as image. It must also be copied as text into the question.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to cast from `HMENU` to `UINT_PTR`. Either use a `reinterpret_cast`:

```
AppendMenuA(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(hSubMenu), "Tool");
```

or a C-style cast:

```
AppendMenuA(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hSubMenu, "Tool");
```

Comment: When using C++, you should stick with C++-style casts only, stay away from C-style casts, unless the code needs to be compilable in C as well.

Comment: can anynone tell why cast is required when doc says to pass a HMENU handle?

Comment: The function signature requires a `UINT_PTR`. The documentation assumes developers understand how to convert between incompatible types. If you're reading the documentation till the end, you'll find a link to [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-menus), too.

Comment: The cast is required because the parameter is used for different things depending on the specified flags.

Comment: this is common in the Win32 API. That parameter is either an identifier to a menu item or a handle to a menu depending on the flags. Handles and identifiers are both integral types but they are *different* types so you have to cast.